# how to place the content beneath the fixed header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have placed two divs beneath the header and made it as fixed then my divs are not visible it is going inside the fixed. Kindly help me in this without using margin-top because if I want to use multiple divs after header it might not be correct.

```js
var Deb = [];

$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  Deb.push(document.location);

});
```

```css
/*add*/

.nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:hover {
  background: transparent!important;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 400 14px/24px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.head-top {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  z-index: 999;
}

#nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 16px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#nav .active {
  background: transparent;
}

#nav li a {
  font: 400 14px/14px 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

#nav li:hover>a {
  background: none;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover,
#nav li ul li:hover>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header id="header">
  <section class="head-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="left-side">
            <h1>sandeep</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="right-side">
            <nav class="navbar ">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#" data-tab='main'>Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#aboutus" data-tab="aboutus">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#gallery" data-tab="gallery">Gallery </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#career" data-tab="career">career</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</header>
```

Comment: You have your `Ul` inside the red container, you may need to move that out to fit in.

Comment: @Manjuboyz ul is a header container right why should we remove that

Comment: So you want the text of nav bar to be moved outside of Red container?

Comment: @Manjuboyz exactly

Comment: I have posted my code, if you wanted to move the `ul` outside then, move the code outside the container. Kindly view the fiddler in full page from my answer.

Comment: @Manjuboyz I didn't  any changes I have copied the code and added another section after the header but it is not displaying after header it is going inside the heder. Kindly refer the js fiddle link here <http://jsfiddle.net/yVf7V/>

Comment: This is a different question?

Comment: @Manjuboyz dude I have explained in the question that I am facing this issue. Please check and suggested me how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `position: fixed` here, you can also use `padding` here.

I calculated the total height of the header and add that total height into `padding-top`

```
section#mainSection {
  padding-top: 75px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  section#mainSection {
    padding-top: 141px;
  }
}
```

Now you need to add your all content inside this `#mainSection` so, no problem will occur.

```js
var Deb = [];

$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  Deb.push(document.location);

});
```

```css
/*add*/

.nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:hover {
  background: transparent!important;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 400 14px/24px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.head-top {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  z-index: 999;
}

#nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 16px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#nav .active {
  background: transparent;
}

#nav li a {
  font: 400 14px/14px 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

#nav li:hover>a {
  background: none;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover,
#nav li ul li:hover>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

section#mainSection {
  padding-top: 75px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  section#mainSection {
    padding-top: 141px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header id="header">
  <section class="head-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="left-side">
            <h1>sandeep</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="right-side">
            <nav class="navbar ">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#" data-tab='main'>Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#aboutus" data-tab="aboutus">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#gallery" data-tab="gallery">Gallery </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#career" data-tab="career">career</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
<section id="mainSection">
  <p>Hello</p>
</section>
```

Comment: don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!